# Как проверять наличие роли у юзера для бота дискорд?

Tags: python, бот, discord, discord.py

Как можно проверить наличие роли у юзера дискорд? Хочу сделать специальную роль, чтобы бот выполнял команды только тех юзеров, у которых есть эта роль, например "Админ". А если роли нет, писал, что им нужна такая-то роль. В пайтоне сильно не разбираюсь, библиотека

Comment: Ну сохраняйте словарь `id -> роль` и проверяйте по нему

Answer (score 2):

есть такая вещь:
`@commands.has_any_role()`
внутри скобок id ролей через запятую
или если тебе нужна проверка внутри функции то записывается так:
`if role in member.roles:`
role - сама роль

Answer (score 1):

есть вариант

```
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
```

функция будет выполнять если у человека есть роль администратора

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]